# JS target function comes to constructor not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor

I am working on drawing moving rectangles on my canvas. I made a template function for the test purpose and it works, but since i want to draw more of the rectangles with same animation effect I have to make this template function comes to the constructor, getContextand now the problem occurs:

the template function:

```
ctx = getContext('2d');
var boxHeight = canvas.height/40;
var boxWidth = canvas.width/20;

function drawBox(){
    var x = 20;
    var y = canvas.height;
    var w = boxWidth;
    var h = boxHeight;
    var timer = 0;
    var ladder = Math.floor(Math.random()*((canvas.height*0.5)/boxHeight)) + 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < ladder; i++){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl('+Math.abs(Math.sin(timer) * 255)+', 40%, 50%)';
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.stroke();
        y -= boxHeight;
        timer += Math.random()*0.3;
    }
}

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    drawBox();  
}
animate();
```

this template function `drawBox()`just working fine, then i tried to enclose its properties into a `Box()`constructor object:

```
function Box(x, width) {
  this.postion = {
    x: x,
    y: canvas.height
  };
  this.width = width;
  this.height = canvas.height / 40;
  this.colorTimer = 0;
  this.draw = function() {
    this.colorTimer += Math.random() * 0.3;
    var ladder = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.height * 0.5) / boxHeight)) + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ladder; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + Math.abs(Math.sin(this.colorTimer) * 255) + ', 40%, 50%)';
      ctx.fillRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
      this.postion.y -= this.height;
    }
  }
}
var myBox = new Box(20, boxWidth);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  myBox.draw();
}
animate();
```

this is not working, i have been stuck with this about 2 hours and i don't think there is any method or properties difference between my `Box`constructor and my `drawBox`object. When it comes to `myBox`object to calling its `draw()`method, there is nothing pop out on the screen.

I am wondering did i just miss something important when creating `Box`constructor object? Could someone give me a hint please?

Comment: The `draw` method should probably be in `Box.prototype.draw` instead of being defined in every object. But it should work the way you wrote it, too.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: No error....just the rectangle fade away rapidly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Todesengel mentioned, the real issue here is, you are re-initializing all the variables each time the template function (`drawBox`) is called. But you are not doing the same for the constructor. To resolve this, put **`this.colorTimer = 0`** and **`this.postion.y = canvas.height`** insde the draw method (*as these are the  variables that need to be re-initialized)*.

However, there are other issues :

- you are increasing the timer variable inside the `for` loop, in template function, but not doing the same for constructor
- as @Barmar mentioned, you should define **`draw`** method as `Box.prototype.draw`, for efficiency *(not mandatory though)*

Here is the revised version of your code :

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var boxHeight = canvas.height / 40;
var boxWidth = canvas.width / 20;

function Box(x, width) {
   this.postion = {
      x: x,
      y: canvas.height
   };
   this.width = width;
   this.height = canvas.height / 40;
}

Box.prototype.draw = function() {
   this.colorTimer = 0;
   this.postion.y = canvas.height;
   var ladder = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.height * 0.5) / this.height)) + 1;
   for (var i = 0; i < ladder; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + Math.abs(Math.sin(this.colorTimer) * 255) + ', 40%, 50%)';
      ctx.fillRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
      this.postion.y -= this.height;
      this.colorTimer += Math.random() * 0.3;
   }
}

var myBox = new Box(20, boxWidth);

function animate() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   myBox.draw();
   window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ohhh now I see it's the position.y not initializing every time so the animation won't last. Thanks to you and @Todesengel .but I will need to recap the "prototype"concepts in OOJs

Answer (score 2):

I believe the important thing to note here is that in your first case, there is a new `drawBox` function being called every time, with the variables being instantiated and initialized, or "reset", each time. In your second case, the myBox object is not being recreated each time, so you have left over variables. These will not behave the same way. It should work as expected if you move `var myBox = new Box(20, boxWidth);` into the `animate` function.

Another fix, if you don't want to do recreate the myBox object for each call, is to reset the left over variables after each animate call. It would be more efficient, and probably more desirable, to do it this way.

Comment: Sorry I am not really get your point here, may I understand as in the constructor approach, myBox().draw only calling the draw()function itself each time, with out initiate the property variable. So the position.y will keep decreasing is it?

Comment: And could you please show me the code solution? Cause I am intend to make more boxes pop out on the screen and I might need a constructor but for now I am kinda confused with how this constructor object should be build, should I enclose all the properties in a for loop there ?

Comment: Please see @ℊααnd's answer. It explains things well. :) I recommend setting his/her answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify `this.position.y` in the `draw` method.

So remove this assignment from the loop:

```
  this.postion.y -= this.height;
```

... and change the following lines to dynamically add `-i*this.height`:

```
  ctx.fillRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y-i*this.height, this.width, this.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y-i*this.height, this.width, this.height);
```

As others have said, you should better define the method on the prototype. And `colorTimer` should change in the `for` loop. I think you could do with a local variable though.

Demo:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var boxHeight = canvas.height/40;
var boxWidth = canvas.width/20;

function Box(x, width) {
  this.postion = {
    x: x,
    y: canvas.height
  };
  this.width = width;
  this.height = canvas.height / 40;
}

Box.prototype.draw = function() {
    var ladder = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.height * 0.5) / boxHeight)) + 1;
    var colorTimer = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ladder; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + Math.abs(Math.sin(colorTimer) * 255) + ', 40%, 50%)';
      ctx.fillRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y-i*this.height, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.postion.x, this.postion.y-i*this.height, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
      colorTimer += Math.random() * 0.3;
    }
};

var myBox = new Box(20, boxWidth);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  myBox.draw();
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```